# Ansible documentation

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I would like to check if there is anyways to get the following documentation from RHEL8 system without internet access :

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html

I have tried ansible-doc for these details but to no avail. Any advice or tips given will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, `ansible-config list`
or 
`/usr/share/doc/ansible-doc/html/reference_appendices/config.html`

For the second, `/usr/share/doc/ansible-doc/html/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html`

Comment: Thanks. ansible-config list helped. But i am not able to see the html pages. I am still checking further on that.

Comment: It's possible you did not install the documentation (`ansible-doc`).